# TCA9548A (I2C multiplexer) works for a few minutes and then hangs

Tags: i2c, communication

I'm having trouble getting the [TCA9548APWR](https://www.digikey.co.uk/product-detail/en/texas-instruments/TCA9548APWR/296-34905-1-ND/3615448) to communicate for longer than a few minutes. I'm only able to get it to "reset" by resoldering it. I have used both an Arduino Mega and a Beaglebone Black to communicate with it (successfully, for a few minutes).

Here's the overall schematic and board design below. Currently I have only installed the +3v / +5v / +12v power converters, the [MCP23017T-E/SO](https://www.digikey.co.uk/product-detail/en/microchip-technology/MCP23017T-E-SO/MCP23017T-E-SOCT-ND/5358289) (which I will use to drive a relay board), and one I2C sensor I'm using the test read/write capabilities.

This is a tough question to ask since I have little insight into what's causing the issue, so apologies if this is too vague – please ask any clarifying questions you may have. Thank you!

**Edit**: I clarified the exact chips I'm using with links

[image: Schematic]
The I2C Multiplexer is the chip in question, right in the middle.
[image: Board]
This board image may be unreadable. If you'd like to check out the Eagle file, I can add a link.

Comment: It's hard to search your image of the schematic, but is GND and GND_logic tied together somewhere?

Comment: What do you mean by resoldering? Resoldering the pins? Replacing the chip completely?

Comment: dmayman - (a) Which setting did you use in your tests for `J9` (supply for MCP23017) - 5V or 3.3V? (b) What I2C sensor did you use (you didn't specify it exactly) and what supply voltage did you use for it (5V or 3.3V)? (c) Do you have an oscilloscope and experience using it? (d) As just asked by *Huisman*, can you be clear about the "resoldering" statement? I interpret it as being you do just need to resolder the connections on the same IC - no replacement. Please confirm. That "fix" is something I've seen for a specific type of problem before, so confirmation of the interpretation helps.

Comment: Some I2C pull up resistors are 1K and some are 10K. The latter seems quite large. What's the reason for having 10K?

Comment: I see many potential issues. That needs some more info. What I2C speeds are you using? Where exactly does the I2C communication jam, you must have a debug serial print where I2C fails, right? Which bus on the mux, which address trying to talk? Is there a retry somewhere?

To help debug this, please draw a diagram or write a list which bus is connected where, and what size pullups each bus segment has.
Some other issues/questions:
-What is the address of TCA9548, are these pins properly biased as well?
-Is there pullups on DAC I2C bus? I don't see them, and that's bad.

Comment: @ChrisKnudsen I am using two LM2596 step down DC converters (breakout boards) to go from 24v > 12v and 24v > 5v. These step down boards have an In+, In-, Out+, Out-. I chose not to connect the In- (GND on my schematic) to the Out- (GND_LOGIC), to preserve any isolation the step down board might have, though after checking the connection it seems that those pins do connect on the step down board. I think we can consider them the same.

Comment: @Huisman To clarify "resoldering" and the exact IC, this is a [TCA9548APWR](https://www.digikey.co.uk/product-detail/en/texas-instruments/TCA9548APWR/296-34905-1-ND/3615448) smd IC. When resoldering, I am using a reflow gun to heat up the chip/board, take it off completely, putting it back on again and checking all connections.

Comment: @SamGibson a) I'm supplying 3.3V to the MCP23017. b) TCA9548APWR c) I do not but have been thinking of getting one for a while...would be incredible right now. d) see my comment above. I have done the resolder trick as mentioned above probably 5+ times with the same pattern of working to failing within a few minutes to 20 min or so. I have never used a replacement chip (I only bought 1)

Comment: @Justme I'm not sure what I2C speeds I'm using, but I have been using the Arduino Wire library with default settings, if that helps. Regarding the jam, it's happening at the between the Arduino and the TCA – *not* between the TCA and slaves on one of its busses. When communication *does* work between the Arduino (or Beaglebone) and the TCA, I have no problem communicating with slaves. I can replicate the symptom with an Arduino sketch that seeks and reports slaves on all channels of the TCA. The program hangs as soon as I call Wire.endTransmission().

Comment: @Justme When testing with the Beaglebone / Python, there is a retry which runs 4-5 times to no avail. The address of the TCA is set to 0x77 with the address pins all set to HIGH (3.3v). As of now, only 2 slaves are connected to the TCA – the MCP as noted originally is connected to channel 1 and a light sensor is connected to channel 7. The problem continues without the light sensor plugged in but I will try disconnecting the MCP to see if that changes anything. No other components (aka the DAC) are plugged in yet, but you bring up a good point about pull-ups everywhere.

Comment: @Huisman Will varying pull up values cause issues? The areas where the 1k resistors will be haven't been added yet (though I have had those working in the past successfully, during periods when the TCA was working). 10k was chosen by the original designer of the board. Not sure why – would 4.7k be more suitable?

Comment: Well the Arduino Wire library actually does the I2C transaction when endTransmission() is called (I don't know Arduino, I had to look it up), so in fact it means that whole transaction may be failed from the start! Does it hang or does it return an error code?

Comment: It just hangs. Meaning - it won't output any more to the serial logger or progress through the code. If I disconnect out the SDA pin from the Arduino to the TCA while the program is hanging, it stops hanging and proceeds. I don't this is a code error because it works fine temporarily.

Comment: If so it might mean the previous I2C transaction left the system in a state it can't recover. For instance you selected a MUX port that cannot communicate for some reason. Also if it does not work after resetting the Arduino/Beaglebone, it means it still can't communicate as you have no way of resetting the MUX, even if it has a reset oin for exactly this reason. Turning power off is your only way to reset it. My guess is it's really not the soldering that helps, but turning power off for long enough time, so soldering it any more would be pointless in my opinion.